# retrieve Route name in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-4

Is it possible to retrieve a route by name?

for exemple, if I register a route with a name like below:

```
 Route::get('dashboard', array(
        'as' => 'my_route_name',
        function()
        {
            ...;
        })
    );
```

then later on, I would like to retrieve the URL for this route.

Something like

```
$myRoute = Route::getRoutebyname("my_route_name");
Redirect::to($myRoute::url());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Laravel 4, though it is slightly different from Laravel 3.

You simply need to use the `redirect` function on the `Redirect` class, instead of the `to` function.

So, yours would look like this:

```
return Redirect::route('my_route_name');
```

See the [Laravel 4 routing documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) for more information.

Comment: Well in fact i'm using route name all over my app. ( to get more flexibility on the url names )
So i'm always using redirect::route.

But at some point of my app, I need to convert an URL into the equivalent route name.



ex:

http://mywebsite.com/dashboard

I want to know if "dashboard" exist in all registered routes and if yes, what is the name of that route.

( that way I will continue to use the redirect::route model, instead of redirect::to )

Comment: I think your question wasn't clear enough. Also, a don't really understand what you want here. The code you gave didn't explain what you really want.

Comment: ok, so  I have the following filter :
`
Route::filter('admin-auth', function()
{
if ( ! Sentry::check())
{
Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
return Redirect::route('admin_login');
}
});`

After the user is authentified, i want to redirect him to the loginRedirect session value. But the loginRedirect value is an URI, and I want to keep the name route redirection, so instead of doing 
`return Redirect::to (Session::get('loginRedirect'));`
I want to do :
`return Redirect::route (xxx);`

I want check in registered routes, if one match to loginRedirect, and if yes retrieve it name